# URL Rewrite domain in NGINX is not working

Tags: nginx, dns

I wish any request for my domain. * Redirect and re-write the link to domain.com

My configuration:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name domain.*;

    # if is different of domain.com i rewrite
    if ($host !~* domain\.com) {
        return          301 http://portal-homolog.virturian.com$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

EDIT1: 
Thanks to @IvanShatsky, i fix the syntax error, now the script work, but not as i expected, when i acess the domain.com.br iam getting 'This site can’t be reached' error. What i want is to redirect to domain.com when i try to access the domain.com.br or others like domain.com.*

Comment: Add space after `if` )) And you don't need the parentheses around `domain.com`. And since you're using `domain.com` string as regex pattern, shield the dot with slash: `if ($host !~* domain\.com) { ...`

Comment: Thanks @IvanShatsky, now the script work but not as i expected, now, when i acess the domain.com.br iam getting 'This site can’t be reached' error

Comment: Is the main domain `domain.com` working with this configuration?

Comment: @IvanShatsky Yes

Comment: I think it is because string `domain.com.br` is matched against regex pattern `domain\.com`. Use pattern `domain\.com$` if you really need case insensitive string matching. I would use `if ($host != domain.com)` for this case (but this is case sensitive comparsion).